# Fancybox get ID of the link

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have this link

```
<a class='btn btn-top' data-fancybox data-src='#hidden-content' id='"+CriId+"' href='javascript:;'>Product</a>
```

And here's the content that appears on fancybox. I have a table with rows. How can I get the id of the "a href" (CriId) which is dynamic?

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="display: none; width:600px" id="hidden-content">
  <table id="tab1-list-search"> 
   // this is a loop
     <tr><td></td></tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

When user clicks on the tr of the table, I am able to get the value of the td, but not the id of the link. I need the id of the link so that I can append the selected td value to the parent table row.

```
$("#tab1-list-search tr").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            var value=$(this).find('td:eq(1)').html();

            alert(value);
        });
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the actual question would be - "How to get current link", right? This is how you can do that:

```
$.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig
```

then you can get ID using `attr('id')`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. I'm not able to pass the ID through fancy box but I have able to pass it after I changed the plugin to colorbox.